# Disposing of things in ASP.NET Class

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have a site which uses a C# class file, and at the top of the file, I have:

`JTSEntities database = new JTSEntities();` (an ADO.NET thingy).

I have it right up the top because I don't really feel like writing the same thing over and over again.

But it raises one question... Because it's up the top there, how will it get disposed, and when - and how can I dispose of it (or do I need to) when the user closes the page?

Comment: Is it static? What is it visibility?

Comment: `protected JTSEntities database = new JTSEntities();`

Comment: ok, thanks. I'm writing an answer

Comment: "top of the file" by itself doesn't tell us a lot. The order of declarations can be changed without changing the behavior of the class at all.

Comment: Does JTSEntities need to be explicitly closed? Does it implement IDisposable?

Comment: It does not yet implement IDisposable (I forgot about IDisposable - it's been a while...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so, based on the type of the attribute, we can say that it's an `instance attribute`. This means that this attribute **will have the same lifecyle as the object that has it**, unless its instance is passed to another object.

If it's protected, then only the owner object and its childs (that is, objects that inherit from this class) will have access to it. If you don't pass it as a reference argument, then we're ok with the first statement: it will be cleaned by the GC as soon as the object is cleaned.

If you just use this object on a regular webform page lifecycle, then you don't have to worry with disposing it. The page lifecycle will do it for you.

Regards

Answer (score 6):

It is bad practice to hold on to anything that wraps a database connection for longer than needed.

The best practice would be to release the database connection as soon as it is no longer needed for the current operation (such as populating initial values, etc.), e.g. something like

```
using (JTSEntities database = new JTSEntities())
{
    // Use database
}
```

if it implements IDisposable.

If for some reason you *must* keep it alive for the duration of the page, be sure you call an appropriate method to release resources (.Close(), .Dispose(), etc.) in the page close event handler.

Comment: +1 - doing the wrong thing because it saves the programmer from cutting and pasting a line a few times seems like a bad decision.

Comment: Thank you Eric. The reason I'm not releasing right away is because I've been told to cut down on DB connections, so I thought I'd try to make them last a little longer by: Only Disposing of the connection when the page is closed (detected via JS) and/or when the User's Session ends, or when they navigate to another page.

Comment: Eric, note that the first sentence may not be true to every situation. Think about the NHibernate SessionFactory object. It's strongly recommended to keep its instance as longer as possible.

Comment: (continued) However, you're right about close, dispose and so on. +1 for that

Comment: DB connections should come from a connection pool.  Making them last longer actually makes the connection pool less efficient since connections are held longer than needed... so that advice sounds flawed.  Given that this is apparently a web app (from your comment) that advice is especially poor.  What if you have 1000 web pages open??  That will destroy your database.  What if you have 10,000 open?

Comment: @AndreCalil: I don't know the specifics of the NHibernate SessionFactory, but I would assume the factory loads *metadata* but does *not* hold a persistent connection to the database (perhaps it provides a method to get a connection as-needed?).  Loading metadata can be expensive justifying the advice.  Holding a connection to the database when it's not needed will kill any DB.  I'm quite sure NHibernate doesn't do that...

Comment: @EricJ You're right. SessionFactory admins the connection pool and all the metadata regarding the DB access. I was just concerned about the amplitude of your sentence. However, if you're talking about an specific connection (or event transaction, what would be worse), then we're ok. =)

Answer (score 2):

Implement `IDisposable` in this class and dispose of this object inside the `Dispose()` method.  When using this class, make sure you call Dispose when you are done (preferably with a `using` block)

Beyond that, you don't need to worry about it.

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    protected JTSEntities database = new JTSEntities();

    public void Dispose() 
    {
        database.Dispose();
    }
}

// When calling this class

using(MyClass cls = new MyClass())
{
    // Do Stuff
}  // Dispose is automatically called here.
```

Comment: If JTSEntities wraps a DB connection, it's bad practice to keep it open longer than needed.

Comment: Yes.  I'm making the assumption here that `MyClass` is called from the  page and the using statement is in the page.